# How to display value from a combobox in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to learn Expression Blend and SilverLight. What I'm trying to achieve is output the selected item from the combobox into a textBlock. Can any one point me in the right direction or show me some C# on how this is done? This is my current code:

```
private void GetSubmitBtn(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Message.Text =
        "Hello there " + this.Firstname.Text + " " + this.Surname.Text
        + ". You come from "  +  this.Origin.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="Names">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="John Doe" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jane Doe" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jack Black" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jake White" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Kelly Blue" />
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=Names}" />
```

And just use a converter to translate into your "Hello ...." string.

You can do it with Sample Data as well.  Create some sample data with a Column named FullName.

In your XAML reference your Sample Data (similar to this)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SampleData:SampleDataSource x:Key="SampleDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then your `ComboBox` and `TextBlock` would change to this.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Names" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.FullName, ElementName=Names}" />
```

Comment: Thanks but, the combo box has sample data bound to it so this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`

Or

```
((OriginClass)Origin.SelectedItem).value;
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. When i run my code it outputs "Expression.Blend.SampleData.OriginData.Item"

Answer (score 0):

Bind the text of your textblock to the combobox.Text.

Comment: that is not true, because he wants "Hello there blablabla" in his textblock, and not just the text of the combobox

Answer (score 0):

you can display selected value of combobox into textbox in silverlight as follows:

```
TextBox1.Text = (cmbApplicationStatus.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

here, `cmbApplicationStatus` is the name of your combobox